# Getting list entries on a specific axis

Tags: python, list

So I have a list like this:

```
    [a,1]
A = [b,2]
    [c,3]...
```

What I want is to generate two seperate lists or arrays like this:

```
    [a]            [1]
B = [b]    and C = [2]   or B = [a,b,c,...] and C = [1,2,3,...]
    [c]...         [3]...
```

I tried doing it with a for loop and it seems to work for now but I'd like to find a more elegant way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
A = [['a',1],['b',2],['c',3]]
B, C = map(list,zip(*A))
```

---

```
print(B)
# ['a', 'b', 'c']
print(c)
# [1, 2, 3]
```